# Beginner's Problem

Tags: scripting

Suppose I have an expression like $7zz_1+5zz_1-\frac{7z_1}{y}+\frac{5z_1}{l}$. How do I convert it to $7(z-\frac{1}{y})z_1+5(z+\frac{1}{l})z_1$. Please help.

Comment: have you tried "Simplify"?

Comment: Can you give a descriptive title to the question? Can you explain how you arrived to this specific form instead of the many other possible ones?  Otherwise I'd say the question is not fully specified.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[a,b]    
Simplify[a*z*z1 + b*z*z1 - a*z1/y + b*z1/l] /. {a -> 7, b -> 5}
```

> (5 (1/l + z) + 7 (-(1/y) + z)) z1